LF will be replaced by CRLF next time git touches it - how to make git execute this?
I'm trying to diff two filesets - one received by a vendor and one in a git repo, so I'm using git diff --name-only repo/files/ shipped/files/ to see what files have been affected.
I have git config core.autocrlf true already, so I'm expecting git to go ahead and do this - that's fine by me because it makes the diff sensible. However, it doesn't seem like git diff counts as "touching" the file enough to replace the line endings as it should.
I did a git add * in the repo, however the fileset I've been sent is not a repo, so I still get the error there.
git config core.autocrlf false does not make the warning go away, as I expected it would have.
I'm fine with replacing the line endings, but how do I encourage git to go ahead and do so?


turning a plain directory into a repo is actually pretty simple :

cd shipped/
git init


you can add your own directory as a remote for that new repo:

git remote add mine /path/to/repo
git fetch mine


use git diff from within this new repo:

# if you set this variable only locally:
git config core.autocrlf true

git diff --name-only mine/main
git diff --name-only mine/my/branch


You can actually pull this off without duplicating your repo: you can instruct git to use the .git/ directory from your repo and use shipped/ as its worktree:
git --git-dir=repo/.git/ --work-tree=shipped/  diff --name-only


note : I initially suggested to use one of the --ignore-* options for git diff, but apparently these options do not kick in when you run git diff --name-only outside of a repository.
